# Spawn a new thread as soon as another has finished

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I've an expensive function that need to be executed 1000 times. Execution can take between 5 seconds and 10 minutes. It has thus a high variation.
I like to have multiple threads working on it. My current implementation devised these 1000 calls in 4 times 250 calls and spawns 4 threads. However, if one thread has a "bad day", it has much longer to finish compared to the other 3 threads.

Hence I like to do a new call to the function whenever a thread has finished a previous call - until all 1000 calls have been made.

I think a thread-pool would work - but if ever possible I like to have a simple method (=as less additional code as possible). Also task-based design goes into this direction (I think). Is there an easy solution for this?

Comment: openmp with dynamic scheduling

Comment: You can use a library implementing thread pools. Intel's tbb, Microsoft PPL or Apple GCD come to mind and should cover most platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize a semaphore with 1000 units.  Have each of the 4 threads loop around a semaphore wait() and the work function.

All the threads will then work on the function until it has been executed 1000 times. Even if three of the threads get stuck and take ages, the fourth will handle the other 997 calls.

[Edit]
Meh.. aparrently, the standard C++11 library does not include semaphores. A semaphore is, however, a basic OS sunchro primitive and so should be easy enough to call, eg. with POSIX.

Comment: If you want to use standard C++ APIs only, then an atomic variable can be used to maintain the counter. And if using the POSIX semaphore, make sure to use `sem_trywait()` so the thread can exit when the counter reaches 0 instead of blocking on the semaphore.

Comment: An atomic var could indeed be used instead.  If this '1000 calls' is only to be executed once during an app run, it is a better idea than a semaphore - less overhead.   If the four threads need to be kept around for another run later, or whatever, then the semaphore is a better plan.

Answer (score 0):

Given that you have already been able to segment the calls into separate entities and the threads to handle. Once approach is to use [`std::package_task`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/packaged_task) (with its associated `std::future`) to handle the function call, and place them in a queue of some sort. In turn, each thread can pick up the packaged tasks and process them.

You will need to lock the queue for concurrent access, there may be some bottle necking here, but compared to the concern that a thread can have "a bad day", this should be minimal. This is effectively a thread pool, but it allows you some control over the execution of the tasks.

Another alternative is to use [`std::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) and specify its [launch policy as `std::launch::async`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/launch), the disadvantage it that you do not control the thread creation itself, so you are dependent on how efficient your standard library is controlling the threads vs. how many cores you have.

Either approach would work, the key would be to measure the performance of the approaches over a reasonable sample size. The measure should be for time and resource use (threads and keeping the cores busy). Most OSes will include ways of measuring the resource usage of the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can use either one of the reference implementation of [Exectuors](https://github.com/chriskohlhoff/executors) and then call the function via

```
#include <experimental/thread_pool>

using std::experimental::post;
using std::experimental::thread_pool;

thread_pool pool_{1};

void do_big_task()
{
    for (auto i : n)
    {
        post(pool_, [=]
        {
            // do your work here;
        });
    }
}
```

Executors are coming in C++17 so I thought I would get in early.

Or if you want to try another flavour of executors then there is a [more recent implementation](https://github.com/ccmysen/executors_r6) with a slightly different syntax.